# Map List onto shifted self

Tags: functional-programming, elm

I have finally found an excellent entry point into functional programming with elm, and boy, do I like it, yet I still lack some probably fundamental elegance concerning a few concepts.

I often find myself writing code similar to the one below, which seems to be doing what it should, but if someone more experienced could suggest a more compact and direct approach, I am sure that could give some valuable insights into this so(u)rcery.

What I imagine this could boil down to, is something like the following
(`<->` is a vector subtraction operator):

```
edgeDirections : List Vector -> List Vector
edgeDirections corners = List.map2 (\p v -> p <-> v) corners (shiftr 1 corners)
```

but I don't really have a satisfying approach to a method that would do a `shiftr`.

But the rules of stackoverflow demand it, here is what I tried. I wrote an ugly example of a possible usage for `shiftr` (I absolutely dislike the `Debug.crash` and I am not happy about the `Maybe`):

Given a list of vectors (the corner points of a polygon), calculate the directional vectors by calculating the difference of each corner-vector to its previous one, starting with the diff between the first and the last entry in the list.

`[v1,v2,v3] -> [v1-v3,v2-v1,v3-v2]`

Here goes:

```
edgeDir : Vector -> ( Maybe Vector, List Vector ) -> ( Maybe Vector, List Vector )
edgeDir p ( v, list ) =
  case v of
    Nothing ->
      Debug.crash ("nono")

    Just vector ->
      ( Just p, list ++ [ p <-> vector ] )


edgeDirections : List Vector -> List Vector
edgeDirections corners =
  let
    last =
      List.head <| List.reverse corners
  in
    snd <| List.foldl edgeDir ( last, [] ) corners


main =
  show <| edgeDirections [ Vector -1 0, Vector 0 1, Vector 1 0 ]
```

I appreciate any insight into how this result could be achieved in a more direct manner, maybe using existing language constructs I am not aware of yet, or any pointers on how to lessen the pain with `Maybe`. The latter may `Just` not be possible, but I am certain that the former will a) blow me away and b) make me scratch my head a couple times :)

Thank you, and many thanks for this felicitous language!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Elm had built-in [`init` and `last`](http://s3.amazonaws.com/lyah/listmonster.png) functions, this could be cleaner.

You can get away from all those Maybes by doing some pattern matching. Here's my attempt using just pattern matching and an accumulator.

```
import List exposing (map2, append, reverse)

shiftr list = 
  let shiftr' acc rest =
    case rest of
      [] -> []
      [x] -> x :: reverse acc
      (x::xs) -> shiftr' (x::acc) xs
  in shiftr' [] list

edgeDirections vectors =
  map2 (<->) vectors <| shiftr vectors
```

Notice also the shortened writing of the mapping function of `(<->)`, which is equivalent to `(\p v -> p <-> v)`.

Suppose Elm *did* have an `init` and `last` function - let's just define those quickly here:

```elm
init list =
  case list of
    [] -> Nothing
    [_] -> Just []
    (x::xs) -> Maybe.map ((::) x) <| init xs

last list =
  case list of
    [] -> Nothing
    [x] -> Just x
    (_::xs) -> last xs
```

Then your `shiftr` function could be shortened to something like:

```elm
shiftr list =
  case (init list, last list) of
    (Just i, Just l) -> l :: i
    _ -> list
```

Comment: This is exactly the pattern I had seen previously and thought it could be applicable here. Thank you for the demonstration! Just out of curiousity, does `(x::xs)` imply, that `x` is not `Nothing`? Edit: strike that, I am sure it does not imply that, that's why this is advantageous, got it.

Answer (score 0):

Just after I "hung up", I came up with this, but I am sure this can still be greatly improved upon, if it's even correct (and it only works for n=1)

```
shiftr : List a -> List a
shiftr list =
  let
    rev =
      List.reverse list
  in
    case List.head rev of
      Nothing ->
        list

      Just t ->
        [ t ] ++ (List.reverse <| List.drop 1 rev)


main =
  show (shiftr [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ] |> shiftr)
```